# Define dateTime type element that can be nillable, empty or absent

Tags: java, xml, xsd, cxf

As said in the title, I'm having a problem with creating an xs:element with the type="xs:dateTime", that can be nillable (nillable="true"), have no value (be empty) or be absent (minOccurs="0"), and will be able to preserve the type in WSDL.

Now my element looks like this:

`<xs:element name="dateImUsing" type="xs:dateTime" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">`

Which should be just fine, but somehow cxf is changing the type of my element seen in WSDL to anySimpleType. Using only one of the nillable or minOccurs attributes works perfectly fine and the type is preserved.

Ideally this element, that is present in the generated java class, should be wrapped with `JAXBElement<XMLGregorianCalendar>`, but it could be just `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

I've tried all of the solutions I was able to come up with, including custom binding, creating type that could be both nullable dateTime or empty string using unions etc. I thought about creating a list with minimum lenght "0" and maximum lenght "1" with nullable dateType element, but I'm afraid it might be too complicated.

Is it any simple way of achieving what I need?

Comment: The term 'empty' has a very specific meaning when used in relation to an XML tag. It means that the tag is present, but there is no text content between the open tag and the close tag (or equivalently, the shortform empty tag representation was used). The min/maxOccurs attributes are completely unrelated to whether a tag is empty. They specify how many times the tag can/must appear.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected my question.